# For $X \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ , let $||X||:=\sqrt{Trace(AA^t)}$ , then $||AB|| \le ||A||\space||B|| , \forall A,B \in M(n,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: matrices, analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ be the set of all square matrices of size $n$ with real entries . For $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ , let

$||A||:=\sqrt{Trace(AA^t)}$ , then is it true that $A,B \in M(n.\mathbb R) \implies ||AB|| \le ||A||\space||B||$ ?

Comment: See in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm about the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality that is true because of Cauchy-Scwartz inequality is that $$Tr(A^TB)\le \sqrt{Tr(A^TA)Tr(B^TB)}$$

**Edit:** For symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $A,B$, we have $$Tr(AB)=Tr(A^TB)\le \sqrt{Tr(A^TA)Tr(B^TB)}=\sqrt{Tr(A^2)Tr(B^2)}\le Tr(A)Tr(B)$$ Thus for our case, $$ Tr(ABB^TA^T)=Tr(BB^TA^TA)\le Tr(A^TA)Tr(B^TB)\\\implies \|AB\|\le \|A\|\|B\|$$

Comment: This shows that $\langle A,B \rangle_F \le \|A\|_F \|B\|_F$. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say is that $Tr(A^TB)\le \sqrt{Tr(A^TA)Tr(B^TB)}$

Comment: @Samrat Mukhopadhyay : Cauchy-Scharwtz only proves $|\langle A,B \rangle|=|Tr(AB^t)|\le\sqrt{Tr(AA^t)Tr(BB^t)}$ which is totally different from what I asked .....

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: Not all Matrix norm satisfies $||AB|| \le ||A||\space||B||$ ... otherwise why would I ask it ?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay : See this for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483549/example-of-matrices-that-do-not-satisfy-the-submultiplicative-property

Comment: Sorry, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that $\|AQ\|_F = \|A\|_F$ for an orthogonal matrix $Q$,
and from this you can see that if $v_1,...,v_n$ is orthonormal then
$\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_k \|Av_k\|_2^2$.

It is also straightforward to show that $\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F$ (look at the eigenvalues of $A A^T$).

Then $\|AB\|_F^2 \le \sum_k \|ABv_k\|_2^2 \le \sum_k \|A\|_2^2 \|Bv_k\|_2^2 \le \|A\|_2^2 \sum_k \|Bv_k\|_2^2 = \|A\|_F^2 \|B\|_F^2$.