# Show that $\left\| \exp(A)-\mathbf{1} \right\| \leq e^{\left\|A\right\|}-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, analysis

Have been attempting this question, just wondering if my answer looks alright.

Question: Given $A \in \Bbb{K}^{n\times n}$ show that $\left\| \exp(A)-\mathbf{1} \right\| \leq e^{\left\|A\right\|}-1$

My proof goes as follows

if $\left\| . \right\|$ is the matrix norm with the submultiplicative property $\left\|AB\right\| \leq \left\|A\right\| \left\|B\right\|$

$\left\|\exp(A)-\mathbf{1}\right\| = \left\|\mathbf{1} + A + \frac{1}{2!}A^{2} + \cdots - \mathbf{1} \right\| = \left\|A + \frac{1}{2!}A^{2} + \cdots \right\|$

We know by triangle inequality that

$ \left\|A + \frac{1}{2!}A^{2} + \cdots \right\| \leq \left\|A\right\| + \frac{1}{2!} \left\|A\right\|^{2} + \cdots = e^{\left\|A\right\|} -1 $

Hence

$\left\|\exp(A)-\mathbf{1}\right\| \leq e^{\left\|A\right\|} -1 $

Does this seem alright?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the idea, yeah. But I mean if you want to be rigorous you need to show that your manipulations are all legit. This is depending on context of the proof.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add at the less or equals to that I was making use of the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right even rigorously we should write by the triangle inequality

$$\Vert \sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}A^k-I\Vert\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\Vert A\Vert^k}{k!}$$ 
and we pass to limit $n\to+\infty$ using the continuity of the norm to get the desired inequality.

Comment: Ah, thank you... I should've said explicitly at the less or equals to sign that I was using the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

As the question did not define the kind of norm used here, I would like to point out that if your norm is not *submultiplicative* (i.e. $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$ ), then the statement (and your proof) are false. Often one speaks of a *matrix norm* if this is the case, but these are not the only norms on matrix spaces!

Consider the $p$-norm given in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/483869/336630 - Let us take the same matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $p = 3$. You can calculate that for this given norm, $\| \exp(A) - \mathbf{1}\|_3 \approx 5.071$ whereas $e^{\|A\|_3} -1 \approx 3.891$.

The problem in your proof then lies in your implicit assumption that $\|A^k\| \leq \|A\|^k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Yes, this is very true. I assumed this without making it explicit. Thanks for pointing that out!